# Opening a new tab and getting it handle

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Searching google on the subject I found multiple useful articles, but when I implement them, and open new tab, WindowHandles property of driver contains only 1 handle, instead of 2. Here is an example code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Url = @"http://www.google.com";
        driver.Navigate();

        string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        ReadOnlyCollection<string> originalHandles = driver.WindowHandles;

        var element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("English"));

        Actions newTab = new Actions(driver);
        newTab.KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Shift).Click(element).KeyUp(Keys.Control).KeyUp(Keys.Shift).Build().Perform();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        string tabHandle = wait.Until<string>((d) => {
            string foundHandle = null;
            List<string> newHandles = driver.WindowHandles.Except(originalHandles).ToList();
            if (newHandles.Count > 0)
            {
                foundHandle = newHandles[0];
            }

            return foundHandle;
        });

        driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabHandle);

        // Do whatever you need to on the popup browser, then...
        driver.Close();
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if there are only two windows then simplest answer is please use below code

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

above code will switch to the most recently opened window, which should be the one that just opened when you clicked the link.

try below code alternate way

```
 var currentWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
 var availableWindows = new List<string>(driver.WindowHandles);

   foreach (string mywindows in availableWindows)    {

                    if (mywindows  != currentWindow)
                    {
                        driver.SwitchTo().Window(w);
                         // perform your action
                       }else{ 
                            driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentWindow);
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, but that is the problem: there are 2 tabs opened and only one window handle in WindowHandles.

Comment: ok please instaed of using action class to open new tab please use driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t") hopr this will help

Comment: Seems that whole tabs thing only works with Chrome. Firefox and IE drivers see only one instance.

Comment: hi i verified how to open a new tab in Firefox form a c# selenium guy and he came up with IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't');

Comment: It does open the tab, but the tab does not have handle in driver.WindowHandles collection